# Symfony4 extends controller with route annotation

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, symfony4

I'm building a webapp with `Symfony` and since now I had to repeat a specific pattern for each new controller I built.

For example I have this `AdminController` :

```
/**
 * @Route("/pro/{uniqid}")
 * @ParamConverter("company", options={"mapping":{"uniqid" = "uniqid"}})
 * @Security("is_granted(constant('App\\Security\\Voter\\CompanyVoter::VIEW'), company)")
 * @package App\Controller
 */
 class AdminController extends Controller
 {
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/users/", name="users")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
     public function users(Company $company){}
 }
```

So, each controller must redefine `@Route`, `@ParamConverter` and `@Security` that is extremely redundant.

I tried to create a `LoggedController` that define every annotation, then make `Controller` extends that `LoggedController`, but that does not work.

Is there a solution or should I continue to copy/paste these Annotation each time I create a new `Controller` that needs to implement it ?

EDIT : 
I add the declaration of `Company` entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CompanyRepository")
 */
 class Company
 {
   /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;
```

Comment: Which version of Symfony?

Comment: Sorry, Symfony4

Comment: Please show the `Company` model properties declarations.

Comment: You want the whole properties of Company ? How is that relevant ?

Comment: Looking specifically for the `@Id` declaration.

Comment: I saw you deleted your answer. But in my routing tab I have `users /admin/users/` and `company /pro/company/{id}` for example...
But no `users /pro/company/{id}/admin/users`...

Comment: You can separate controllers that have the same contracts by directories, and then in your routes.yml add your requirements.

Comment: You can use `resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/Pro'` with your desired routing for any Controller within that directory. As for `ParamConverter` since you're not using a standard Id, I recommend your current method, to ensure it is declared within the controller, as opposed to using a [`beforeController`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short, you can but it will be a lot easier to duplicate your annotations in every controller.

But if you wan't to do this anyway, here are some solutions.

---

**Routing**

This is the easy one. You can define a global prefix in the `config/routes/annotations.yaml` file.

If you're using the default config, you can try something like this:

```
# Default controllers
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

# Company controllers
company_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Company/
    type: annotation
    prefix: /pro/{uniqid}
```

All your routes will now start with `/pro/{uniqid}` and you can remove the `@Route` annotation from your controller.

---

**ParamConverter**

You can create your own [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter). Everytime you'll use a `Company` type in an action method, it'll be converted to the matching entity using the `uniqid` attribute.

Something like this:

```
// src/ParamConverter/CompanyConverter.php
<?php

namespace App\ParamConverter;

use App\Entity\Company;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CompanyConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{
    const CONVERTER_ATTRIBUTE = 'uniqid';

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * CompanyConverter constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        $uniqid = $request->attributes->get(self::CONVERTER_ATTRIBUTE);

        $company = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Company::class)->findOneBy(['uniqid' => $uniqid]);

        $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), $company);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    function supports(ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        return $configuration->getClass() === Company::class;
    }
}
```

With this, you can remove the `@ParamConverter` annotation from your controller.

**Security**

You can't use the access_control section of the `security.yaml` file since custom functions are not yet supported.

Otherwise, something like this could have been nice:

```
security:
    ...

    access_control:
        -
            path: ^/pro
            allow_if: "is_granted(constant('App\\Security\\Voter\\CompanyVoter::VIEW'), company)"
```

(Note: It was *fixed* in [Symfony 4.1](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26660) but i don't know yet how it will work).

Instead, you can use a subscriber listening on the `kernel.request` kernel event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Subscriber;

use App\Entity\Company;
use App\Security\CompanyVoter;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class SecurityListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface
     */
    private $authorizationChecker;

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManagerInterface
     */
    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (!$uniqid = $request->attributes->get('uniqid')) {
            return;
        }

        $company = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Company::class)->findOneBy(['titre' => $uniqid]);

        if (!$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted(CompanyVoter::VIEW, $company)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest',
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: For routing, is it possible to do it only for a few Controller ? The pain point is precisely that I need all of that only for certain Controllers.

Comment: You can move these controllers inside a directory and create a second configuration entry in your `annotations.yaml` file. I edited my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Of course, my bad. But for the `ParamConverter` part. Symfony tells me `Unable to guess how to get a doctrine...`

Comment: I think I still have to use `@ParamConverter` annotation, right ?

Comment: For the security concern can a condition be used on the route with the expression builder in conjunction to custom service provider? e.g. https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html

Comment: @BorisLeMéec No, you don't have to use the annotation. It should be automatically converted. Try debugging the class with a `dump` in the `supports` method. If it's not executing, it may be an autoconfiguration problem.

Comment: @fyrye Actually, this is the same as using an access_control in the `security.yaml` file. `is_granted` is not a native expression language method and it can't be used in routing conditions

Comment: I was thinking of something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398724/expression-language-in-conditional-routing-service-in-context

Comment: @BorisLeMéec You may have to register the service manually: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter